# If $|\sin^2 x+ 17 - x^2|=|16-x^2|+2 \sin ^2 x + \cos ^2x$ then $x$ lies in what interval

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

If $|\sin^2 x+ 17 - x^2|=|16-x^2|+2 \sin ^2 x + \cos ^2x~$  then $x$ lies in what interval?

Hints Please? I dont know how to approach this problem.

Comment: Note that $\sin^2x+17-x^2=\sin^2x+1+16-x^2$ and also $2\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1+\sin^2x$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that $|\sin^2x+1+16-x^2|=|16-x^2|+\sin^2x+1$ $(*)$

Set $y=\sin^2x+1$ and $z=16-x^2$. Then $(*)$ reduce to

$|z+y|=|z|+y$. Taking square of both sides we get $y(z-|z|)=0$

Hence, since $\sin^2x+1\neq0$ we have $16-x^2=|16-x^2|$ and this is true only for $ -4\leq x\leq 4$.